# Problems using nvidia drivers/multiple monitors

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia

I have installed elementary os from scratch. I have 4 monitors that I want to use as an extended desktop. These were not working by default so I installed an nvidia driver via "additional drivers".

The driver install seemed to work fine but now after a reboot I just get a black screen.

I'm new to elementary os and have only used Linux as a Web server prior to this.

How can I go about installing and getting multiple monitors working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get rid of the current nvidia driver

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

after that add the current graphics repository by writing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
```

after that use

```
sudo apt update
```

to make downloads from it possible.

To install the latest working driver use

```
sudo apt install nvidia-387
```

if it doesn't work you can open the root terminal at login using
ctrl+alt+f2 and purge the nvidia driver once again to go back to the standard driver

Answer (score 1):

You might find, depending on your hardware, that the displays panel in System Settings does not cope well with multiple monitors, especially if you periodically go about changing them as I do with a laptop (I have 3 different configurations that I work with). I found that installing ARandR was the best solution as it enables you to save the config and reload it later - you won't find it in the AppCentre but it's in the normal packages so `sudo apt install arandr` will work from the terminal.

One tip - don't expect to be able to move windows through the header bar (as you can on certain other OSes). Place your primary monitor (ie with the hearer bar) at the top of your window config.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had problems getting 3 monitors to behave in a consistent manner, but just by installing arandr and running it for the first time, my monitors agreed to comply :-)